# First time app installation gives apid to be null

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

In my main activity's `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onResume` methods, the call `PushManager.shared().getAPID()` is always null when the app is installed for the first time.

However, after the `onResume` method, Urban Airship automatically registers a new `APID` (I placed a button and created a toast to print the `APID`). I want to retrieve this `APID` and store it in my back end server on fresh install. How can I do that?

My question is similar to [this](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/277810-why-is-getpushid-null-the-first-time-) question but I'm looking to register the apid on my own back end server not Urban Airship.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In order to get the UA lib to generate the APID on first install I had to call PUshManager.enablePush().

Its not the ideal solution I wanted but it allowed me to grab the APID and save it to a separate server.

Comment: Ya I called that on app launch. Problem for me was that on app launch itself I wanted to register the id on the server but it came null as it had not finished getting the id from UrbanAirship. I had to create a BroadcastReceiver and wait for action PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED and only after register the id to server.

Comment: ah yeah that makes perfect sense.

Comment: could you please post the answer? I am also having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827850/push-notifications-using-urban-airship-returns-apid-as-null-at-the-first-launch?noredirect=1#comment29482816_19827850