# Push Notifications using Urban Airship returns apID as null at the first launch

Tags: android, null, urbanairship.com

I have successfully integrated urban airship push notification to my android application. I ran into an issue here, that is the apID becomes null with the very first launch and then with the second launch, apId comes correctly.

This is how I grab the apId:

```
String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
```

This is the class that I have used:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static SharedPreferences PREFS_TOKEN;
    public static final String PREFERENCE = "UrbanAirship";
    public static String tokenKey;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(){
           AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
           UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
           PushManager.enablePush();
           Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;

            // use CustomPushNotificationBuilder to specify a custom layout
            CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

            nb.statusBarIconDrawableId = R.drawable.paw;// custom status bar icon

            nb.layout = R.layout.notification;
            nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.paw;// custom layout icon
            nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
            nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
            nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;

            // customize the sound played when a push is received
            // nb.soundUri =
            // Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/"
            // +R.raw.cat);

            String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();

            Logger.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);

            PREFS_TOKEN = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor edit = PREFS_TOKEN.edit();

            if (apid != null && apid != "") {
                edit.putString(PREFERENCE, apid);
                edit.commit();
            } else {
                edit.putString(PREFERENCE, apid);
                edit.commit();
            }

            tokenKey = PREFS_TOKEN.getString(PREFERENCE, "");
            System.out.println("---------- - App APID: " + tokenKey);

            PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
            PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
       }
    }
```

I also have an IntentReceiver class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error/message when you get null apid?

Comment: not an error message, just null at the very first launch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that the reason is a delay, to get the apId, it takes some time, therefore, in your IntentReceiver class, you have to wait for `PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED to fire. From there, you can get the apId:

```
if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
            Log.i(logTag,"Registration complete. APID:" + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)+ ". Valid: "+ intent.getBooleanExtra( PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));
            // Notify any app-specific listeners
            String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();


            Intent launch = new Intent(UAirship.getPackageName()+ APID_UPDATED_ACTION_SUFFIX);
            UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(launch);

        }
```

Comment: how can i get the "action" value?

Comment: how can i get the "action" and APID_UPDATED_ACTION_SUFFIX values?

Comment: how can i get the "action" and APID_UPDATED_ACTION_SUFFIX values?

Comment: It is a Sting, not sure what it does though. please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921968/android-urban-airship-not-get-push-notification